# How to change prototype value which would overwrite objects value? Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

So my objective is to set the **special** property of **card**. In a way that my first three console.log would print false (as default), but after the code it would print true. I tried several ways (describing a method in **card** to set **this.special** to true, and called the method afterwhile. Didnt work). Also just changing **card.special** did not work. Thanks,

```
    function card(name,value,special) {
 this.name = name,
 this.value = value,
 this.special = special
}
var a9 = new card("nine",9,false);
var a10 = new card("Ten",9,false);
var aal = new card("lower",9,false);

console.log(a9.special);
console.log(a10.special);
console.log(aal.special);
//code comes here
console.log(a9.special);
console.log(a10.special);
console.log(aal.special);
```

Comment: you'd have to change a9.special, a10.special and aa1.special individually

Comment: that is the point, that I dont want to use them individually. Because I will have 30-60 different variants.

Comment: 60 variables ... ugh ... why not an array of `card` - then you can use cards.forEach(...) to do things

Comment: I just noticed ... `Var` - not javascript, `Console` - not javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use prototype to store `special`

```
function card(name,value,special) {
  this.name = name;
  this.value = value;
}

card.prototype.special= false;

var a9 = new card("nine",9);
var a10 = new card("Ten",9);
var aal = new card("lower",9);

console.log(a9.special);  //false
console.log(a10.special); //false
console.log(aal.special); //false
```

It should be noted that as long as you don't modify `special` on an object it would keep pointing to the original value in `prototype` but when you change it on some object that one gets its own copy wiz. no longer pointing to the prototype.For example :

suppose now you have an exception card for which you want `special` as being `true`

```
aal.special=true;
console.log(aal.special);//true
```

It won't affect others rather it gets it's own independent copy

```
console.log(a9.special); //false
console.log(a10.special); //false

card.prototype.special= true; // make all true

console.log(a9.special); //true
console.log(a10.special); //true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a prototype function that will console log the variable and change its value.

```
card.prototype.logToggleSpecial = function() {
  console.log(this.special);
  if(!this.special)
    this.special = !this.special;
};
```

Instead of calling console log, just call for example a9.logToggleSpecial(). Already tried this and it works.

Comment: Maybe I wasnt enough specific. I actually dont need to console.log them. I used console.log only to see if my ideas were working.
What I need is a function which affects prototype and change one property of more objects (a9, a10, aal) in the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```js
var counter = 0;

function Card(name, value, special) {
    this.name = name,
    this.value = value,
    this.special = special;
}

defineSpecial(Card.prototype)

function defineSpecial(o) {
    var specialValue;
    Object.defineProperty(o, 'special', {
        get() {
            if (counter++ <= 2) {
                return false;
            }
            return specialValue;
        },
        set(val) {
            specialValue = val;
        }
    });
}

var a9 = new Card("nine",9,true);
var a10 = new Card("Ten",9,true);
var aal = new Card("lower",9,true);
console.log(a9.special);
console.log(a10.special);
console.log(aal.special);
//code comes here
console.log(a9.special);
console.log(a10.special);
console.log(aal.special);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do somethinglike:

```
[a9,a10,aal].forEach(function(c) { c.special = true; });
```

or even

```
var cards = {
    a9: new card("nine",9,false),
    a10: new card("Ten",9,false),
    aal: new card("lower",9,false),
};
console.log(cards.a9.special);
console.log(cards.a10.special);
console.log(cards.aal.special);

Object.keys(cards).forEach(function(key) { cards[key].special = true; });

console.log(cards.a9.special);
console.log(cards.a10.special);
console.log(cards.aal.special);
```

Or if you want to get a little fancy

```
var card = function() {
    var cards = {};
    function card(name,value,special) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.special = special;
        cards[name] = this;
    }
    card.setSpecial = function(b) {
        Object.keys(cards).forEach(function(key) { 
            cards[key].special = b; 
        });
    };
    return card;
}();

var a9 = new card("nine",9,false);
var a10 = new card("Ten",9,false);
var aal = new card("lower",9,false);

console.log(a9);
console.log(a10);
console.log(aal);

card.setSpecial(true);

console.log(a9);
console.log(a10);
console.log(aal);
```